# How to maven deploy rpm with architecture information

Tags: maven-3, rpm-maven-plugin

I use the rpm-maven-plugin from  mojo.codehaus.org to generate my RPM called MyRPM-3.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm. However when I deploy the rpm to artifactory, I get MyRPM-3.0.0.rpm. How can I include the build number (the -1 part) and architecture (the _x86_64 part) in the deployment? I'm using maven 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [release](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/ident-params.html#release) parameter to set the release or you can change the version parameter as well.

For the architecture you can use either the [needarch](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/ident-params.html#needarch) parameter or depending on your needs the [targetArchitecture](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/source-params.html#targetArchitecture)

Comment: All these parameters are for "building" the rpm with the desired name, which I do already. It's the maven deploy where I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attached-rpm goal[1] and set the classifier to be the combination of os and architecture.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/attached-rpm-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

I am probably too late here, but I hope that I can help someone. So you can call:

```
mvn rpm:rpm rpm:version
```

The first goal is pretty simple, it will be made the final rpm package, but the second goal will set properties ${rpm.version} and ${rpm.release} -> [link](https://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/version-mojo.html)

In you case **rpm.version** will be 3.0.0 and **rpm.release** is the 1
and the last one property, which you need is os.arch = x86_64, but it depends on the system, where you build the rpm. Hope it helps.